# How can I keep the second page from printing upside down?

Tags: printing, vb6, printers

I'm using old VB6 code that seems to work perfectly fine on a Win7 desktop.  At some point the code is using the `Printer` object doing things like this...

```
Printer.font.Bold = True
Printer.CurrentX = xpos
Printer.CurrentY = ypos
Printer.Print LinesToPrintArr(LineNum, i)
```

The pages are printing duplex and binding on long edge (top) so that you flip the pages up while being bound on the long edge.  Everything is printed landscape.  On Windows 7 this works without any issues.  However recently we started using OSs such as Windows Server 2012R2 or later.  For some reason, the first page is perfect and the second page (on the back of the first) is printed upside down.

> Note: The application built is actually calling a COM object to do the
>   printing, so making the app (that is running on a win10 machine) run
>   in compatibility mode (win7) while calling a COM object on the server
>   (2016) I don't think would help any.

### Example of how it should look on all OS versions...

[image]

### Example of how it does look on server OS (which is wrong)...

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening on a new server OS (like server 2016) and not on Windows 7?  Is there a control or other support file I might be able to downgrade that Win7 uses to make this function the correct way?  I'm guessing this has to do with the vb6 printer object used inside vb6.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the VB6 code, and not configuration within the printer driver on each of the systems you're testing on? Have you testing printing from within other applications? I don't think VB6 has a "print upside down mode"…

Comment: You should review the printer setup defaults for duplex printing. Frequently there is a 'Flip on long edge' / 'Flip on short edge' option.  If that's different between your two machines, that would explain the "upside down" print.

Comment: I have done extensive testing trying to solve the issue.  My first thoughts as well had to do with the printer drivers and default settings (we usually set those).  In this case nothing we change on the defaults (print drivers) page will be shown in the print out.  We have tried many print drivers (all that have been tested and work on win7).  Now a days there are all these "universal drivers" and you can not download the one just for your OS.  Remember it works fine on Win7 and we are doing the SAME EXACT things (such as defaults etc) as we do on the Win7 machine.

Comment: ...  Even though we are doing the same exact thing as far as settings etc, we have also tried everything we could think of just to manipulate the print...  We have tried all the "flipping" options available and they seem to do absolutely nothing.  Being someone who has had the unfortunate job of continuing to support old vb6 code I did not create I have learned that vb6 and advancements in technology do not go well together.  Ex: vb6 app + server 2016 = issues.

Comment: Did you configure the printer's defaults for all users, or just for one user who isn't the same account the program runs under?

Comment: @Bob77 I'm testing everything under the same user account on the server right now so that should not matter (for the purpose of what i'm testing).  I honestly didn't even know that was possible though.  How can you change defaults for "all users" opposed to just the user logged on?

Comment: Well, from memory: Go to Devices and Printers, right click the printer and select Printer Properties.  Then click the Advanced tab then the Printing Defaults button.  Configure your desired settings and then click OK.  The settings should apply to all users on that computer.

Comment: O well, then yes.  I don't think there is a way to configure the print settings for just one user.  When you set the default preferences (or anything in the printer properties for that mater) I believe it effects all users by default.  So yes that was 100% done.